# How to expand the dataset with 0.5 day in power query?

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have a excel dataset with the following format:
[image]

I would like to generate Dates between Start and End Date. However, there can have non integer days in the `duration` column. How to expand the row if the `duration` column is not integer?

For example,
for staff a,
Since the duration of his/her annual leave is 1.5 days, then,

The expanded dataset will be:

| Name | start | Start end period | end | Leave End eriod | Duration | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 05-11-2023 | pm | 06-11-2023 | pm | 1.5 | 05-11-2023 |
| a | 05-11-2023 | pm | 06-11-2023 | pm | 1.5 | 06-11-2023 |

The first row corresponds to 1 day.
The second row corresponds to the remaining 0.5 days.

My expected outcome is:
[image]

Is it possible to expand it without using ifelse?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and use words to describe the expected outcome and the logic that leads to it? I'm staring at the screenshot and can't tell what you want to achieve.

Comment: The question is updated. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @doraemon  ,,, I think that you have committed one basic mistake since your calculation is beyond 24 Hrs... therefore instead of only Date value you need to use DATE TIME STAMP since the adjacent column has TIME Unit AM & PM ,,,, using Start Period like 05/01/2023 08:00 AM   or 06/01/2023 05 PM  is the correct format & will help also to get correct answer ,,, regardless of Excel or Power Query !!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "expand". Your have not explained your expected outcome at all. The only change I can see between the first table and the outcome is that there is another date column, which seems to have the same date as the first column. Can you please use words that explain the expected result and the processing logic that leads to the result? Something like: The outcome must show another date column that is calculated by adding xxx to yyy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the List.Dates() function. Simply add a new custom column "Date" to your data, with the following code:

```
List.Dates([start], Number.RoundUp([Duration], 0), #duration(1, 0, 0, 0))
```

[image]

And finally, 'Expand to new rows' the column Date to have the desired result:

[image]

[image]